# This IQueryable<T> extension method has no supported translation to SQL :(

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do the following linq 2 sql extension method:

```
public static PagedList<T> ToPagedListOrNull<T>(this IQueryable<T> value,
                                                int index,
                                                int pageSize)
    {
        return value.Count() == 0
        ? null
        : (value is PagedList<T> ? value as PagedList<T> : 
                                   new PagedList<T>(value, index, pageSize));
    }
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Method 'Boolean
>   Contains(System.String)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

I think it's erroring on the `value.Count() == 0` bit .. i think.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, in other words in 'value'.

Try testing that separately to make sure it works.  :)

Comment: Sorry mate - i don't understand :( Are you saying i need to test the 'value' object first? test for what?

Comment: Write a unit test, and test value.Count() == 0.  I am saying there is likely a problem with the query, and not the extension method, or usage thereof.

Comment: +1 @Pure leppie is right, there is clearly an issue with the linq query itself. The extension method is just doing a plain call to Count().